# Parallel processing in shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, parallel-processing, shiny, plotly

i have a shiny app that produces plotly maps with info about specific characteristics of us counties. The app works fine but it takes 40sec in order to create a map every time i call one. I use a reactive expression (rt2) with if and else if in order to do the pre-processing Is there a way to do some kind of parallel processing or something like this to save time?

Sample of dataset

```
County_ID County_Name        EQI    air_EQI  water_EQI   land_EQI sociod_EQI
      <int>       <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1      1001 Autauga, AL  0.0041379  0.9553846 -1.1097280 -0.7065906  0.6704357
2      1003 Baldwin, AL  0.2002343  0.7179643 -0.5659107 -1.0842990  0.5530728
3      1005 Barbour, AL -0.9506388  0.1310074 -0.9780902 -1.2814700 -1.2362940
4      1007    Bibb, AL -1.0889200  0.0652890 -0.9681726 -0.8274103 -0.6000178
5      1009  Blount, AL -0.5139221  0.4021944 -0.7186447 -0.6229339  0.2965088
6      1011 Bullock, AL -2.0828290 -0.3091858 -1.4513350 -1.2580140 -1.8239700
```

## ui.r

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(tidyr)
library(maps)
library(shinydashboard)
library(viridis)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title="Computational Modelling and Investigation of Neuropsychiatric Disease (MIND)",
  tabPanel("Home Tab",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(

               uiOutput("selectcol11"),
               uiOutput("selectsol11")
             ),
             mainPanel(plotlyOutput("plot2")))))
```

## server.r

```
    server <- function(input, output) {

output$selectcol11<-renderUI({
        selectInput("selectcol11","Select Measure",choices = c("EQI","air_EQI","water_EQI",  
                                                                     "land_EQI","sociod_EQI","built_EQI","good_days","bad_days" ),selected = "EQI")
      })
 output$selectsol11<- renderUI({
            sliderInput("selectsol11", "Select Resolution",
                        min = 2, max = 7, value = 5,step =1)})


            rt2 <- reactive({
                if(input$selectcol11== "EQI"){
                foo <- cbind(data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(df$County_Name),',',fixed=TRUE))),df[,c(1,3:10)])
                colnames(foo)[1] <- "County"
                colnames(foo)[2] <- "State"

                foo1 <- map_data("county")

                eqi1 <- foo %>%
                  group_by(County) %>%
                  summarise(EQI = sum(EQI))
                eqi10 <- foo %>%
                  group_by(County) %>%
                  summarise(County_ID = sum(County_ID))
                eqi<- cbind(eqi1,eqi10[,2])
                eqi$County <- tolower(eqi$County) # matching string
                foo1_eqi <- merge(foo1, eqi, by.x = "subregion", by.y = "County")
                foo1_eqi
                final.plot1<-foo1_eqi[order(foo1_eqi$order), ]
                final.plot1$County_Name_ID <- with(final.plot1, paste("County:",subregion, '<br>', "County_ID:", County_ID ))
                final.plot1
                }
                else if(input$selectcol11== "air_EQI"){
                  foo <- cbind(data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(df$County_Name),',',fixed=TRUE))),df[,c(1,3:10)])
                  colnames(foo)[1] <- "County"
                  colnames(foo)[2] <- "State"

                  foo1 <- map_data("county")

                  eqi1 <- foo %>%
                    group_by(County) %>%
                    summarise(air_EQI = sum(air_EQI))
                  eqi10 <- foo %>%
                    group_by(County) %>%
                    summarise(County_ID = sum(County_ID))
                  eqi<- cbind(eqi1,eqi10[,2])
                  eqi$County <- tolower(eqi$County) # matching string
                  foo1_eqi <- merge(foo1, eqi, by.x = "subregion", by.y = "County")
                  foo1_eqi
                  final.plot1<-foo1_eqi[order(foo1_eqi$order), ]
                  final.plot1$County_Name_ID <- with(final.plot1, paste("County:",subregion, '<br>', "County_ID:", County_ID ))
                  final.plot1
                }
            })

            output$plot2 <- renderPlotly ({
                p<-  ggplot(rt2(), aes(x = long, y = lat, group=group,text=County_Name_ID,fill = cut_number(rt2()[,7],input$selectsol11)))
                p<- p+  geom_polygon(colour=alpha("black", 1/2))
                p<- p+coord_equal() 
                p<- p+  viridis::scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE)
                p<- p+ scale_fill_discrete("Measure Density")
                ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("County_Name_ID"))
              })
            }
```

Comment: I have tried to replicate a bigger dataset with you example dataset but this is not easy. In my environment it is very fast, but some plots do not appear, and the `fill = cut_number(rt2()[,7],input$selectsol11)` removed since it produced error. Moreover, some things are weird such as : why do you have your `sliderInput`'s in your `server` AND with the same ID ?

Comment: The exampe works only with specific dataset that unfortunatelly i cannot provide. I have slider in my server as i want uioutput of it. This works do not worry. I was just wondering how i can make it work faster

Comment: You should provide a minimal reproducible example, not just copy & paste all your code.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot reproduce the example, I cannot know what takes time in your app. So I would suggest you to do some profiling while running your application : there is a tool available directly in Rstudio -

> ->  "start profiling"  and then run your application
>
> -> "stop profiling" when the app has loaded.

From that, you will be able to see what is the part that takes most time (or memory).
With what you showed, I'd suggest it is the `foo1 <- map_data("county")` that should take most computation time. Hence, if this is the case you should find out how to speed up this function or find another function. For `map_data()`, I don't think it is relevant to implement parallel processing.